# Is using more data in an analysis of variance inherently better?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, dataset, model

I have a large data set (~50000 rows) with each row representing one hour of data. I want to know if more tags are detected based on equipment model used. The data represents 90 sites (each site recording a different number of hours), with 30 sites using each type of equipment model.

Would it be better to run a model with all 50000 data points (the response variable being detections) or to group the data by site and run my analysis with the average hourly detections per site (the response variable being hits/hour)? And if the later is the case, how do I account for the different number of hours of detection per site?

Comment: Those data won't be independent.  Is it possible to have >1 detection by the same model within an hour?  That is, what are the data like, is it just 0-1, or can it be [0,1,2,...)?

Comment: Yes it is. All sites have recorded minimum 1 tag detection but range above 1000 detections per hour

Comment: Is there some reason why the minimum is 1?  Is it possible to have a 0?  Would the data not be recorded, if there weren't any detections?

Comment: Yes, when this data table was extracted from the sql file, it only pulled data with 'activity'

Comment: That will yield a biased dataset. You need to ensure the 0's are pulled, or, if you can determine what conditions should exist, you can create them & input the 0's.

Comment: Okay I see thank-you! To go back to the original question, once I've extracted the data again with 0s what kind of analysis would you recommend?